# Edit search bar layout magento

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to edit the layout of the search field like change its placeholder, text instead of icon for the search button, etc.

and it seems like its located here:

`/www/cleanz-aire/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml`

I'm working in a child theme so is there any way I can edit it from child theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to just copy core file into your child theme and customize as per your need,

```
app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{childthemme}/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
```

Clear cache. Your changes are applied.

Answer (score 3):

Copy

**vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml**

to your theme

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml**

And edit that file to make changes.

If changes are not reflected then flush cache and check.